# How to change Y Axis label size in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scanpy

I am using scanpy, who uses matplotlib under the hood. I am basically creating a dotplot with this package. I would like to change the y axis label size, how can I do this?

Using this works for enlarging all font sizes for the entire plot, as expected:

```
import scanpy as sc
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams


#generate the dotplot
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 50
sc.pl.dotplot(df,  ["gene"], 'CellType',figsize=(5,15), dendrogram=False)
```

But if I try to do this for the y axis only, it doesn't work:

```
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize']: 5
sc.pl.dotplot(df,  ["gene"], 'CellType',figsize=(5,15), dendrogram=False)
```

I also tried `plt.rcParams.update({'ytick.labelsize': 50})` but that didn't work either. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the rcParams may only affect plots drawn after that command.
Try adding

```
plt.gca().tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=30)
```

to your code. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
plt.gca().tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=30)
plt.show()
```